# determining leading term by inspection

Tags: polynomials

Given an arbitrary polynomial, say univariate with potentially large exponents, is there a way to tell what the largest term is (as $x$ approaches 0) by inspection, without multiplying out all factors?

Consider $f(x)=(x^2 + x - (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3(-x^3(x + 1) + x^2) + x^2 + 1) + 1)$

If the expression is factored it is easy to tell that the term is order $x^2$: $x^2(x - 1)(x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1)$. It is also easy to tell that it is not constant since $f(0)$ is $0$ -- so we know that the term is the lowest power of $x$. We might also get a numerical estimate of the power of the term by calculating $\log(f(a)/f(a/2), 2)$ with a sufficiently small value of $a$ (once we know that $f(0)$ is $0$).

Is there any other way (short of expanding the expression) to determine that the term is $O(x^2)$?

[edited to refer to the term as the one dominating as x approaches 0]

Comment: In your "factored" expression, isn't the leading term $x^9$?

Comment: By leading term I mean the one that dominates as $x->0$

Comment: @smichr That's not what leading term is usually taken to mean. Anyway, the $2$ in $x^2$ is the lowest order $n^{th}$ derivative such that $f^{(n)}(0)\ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, but one must continue testing until that value is found...I am hoping for a more direct approach. {sorry about vocabulary, I am using the name of the method in SymPy that gives that expression}

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but I think expanding the polynomial out is the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Hmm. Replace all right-parens with `)^10`.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(0)$ is $0$ then finding the largest term as $x$ approaches 0 can be accomplished by finding the leading term of the numerator and denominator of $f(1/x)$, $n$ and $d$, respectively. If $g(x) = n/d$ then the largest leading term will be $g(1/x)$.

But finding the leading term is only trivial when there are no sums with sums of interest raised to some power, e.g. $(x^3+x+1)^3 - x^9$ will not have a leading term of $x^9$.